# Unable to change wireless adapter MAC address

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, mac-address

I have a Qualcomm Atheros AR956x wireless network adapter installed but I can't change its MAC address as it doesn't have an option for that. I have tried to change MAC address from registry but it also doesn't work.

Can i change the MAC address for this device?

Comment: MAC Addresses are locked to the hardware. I believe there are ways to spoof it to windows, but all other devices will see the original MAC. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. It is not clear what you are doing, why you would want to change the MAC address and what your expected results are. Sometimes it is better to tell us what you are trying to solve and let us suggest how to do it. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this: http://www.howtogeek.com/192173/how-and-why-to-change-your-mac-address-on-windows-linux-and-mac/

Most network cards will allow you to set a custom MAC address from their configuration panes in the Device Manager, although some network drivers may not support this feature.

First, open the Device Manager. On Windows 8.1, press Windows Key + X and click Device Manager. On Windows 7, press the Windows key, type “Device Manager” to search for it, and click Device Manager.

Locate the network interface you want to modify under Network Adapters, right-click it, and select Properties.

Click the Advanced tab and select Network Address in the list. Your network driver doesn’t support this feature if the option isn’t here.

Enable the Value option and enter your desired MAC address without any separating characters — don’t use dashes or colons. Click OK afterward.

Modern Linux distributions like Ubuntu typically use Network Manager, which provides a graphical way to spoof a MAC address.

For example, on Ubuntu you’d click the network icon on the top panel, click Edit Connections, select the network connection you want to modify, and click Edit. On the Ethernet tab, you’d enter a new MAC address under “Cloned MAC address” and save your changes.

You can also do this the old-fashioned way. This involves taking the network interface down, running a command to change its MAC address, and then bringing it back up. Be sure to replace “eth0” with the name of the network interface you want to modify and enter the MAC address of your choice:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down

sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

You’ll have to modify the appropriate configuration file under /etc/network/interfaces.d/ or the /etc/network/interfaces file itself if you want this change to always take effect at boot time. If you don’t, your MAC address will be reset when you restart.

See the link for pictures and Mac OSX instructions.

Comment: IN the advance tab of my interface there isn't Network Address option .. Does that mean I cant change my interface mac ???